# With ar_pose_marker can the distance between the camera and the ar code be determined?

Tags: ros, frame-id, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coordinates that I get mediange ar_pose_marker do not reflect the distance between the camera and the observed AR code. As much as I move the AR code closer to the camera, the distance between the camera and the AR code can not be seen in the coordinates x, y, z.
In output_frame I put the frame_id of the camera

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280378/with-ar_pose_marker-can-the-distance-between-the-camera-and-the-ar-code-be-determined?/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, it was just a matter of adjusting the "marker_size" parameter

---

Originally posted by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) with karma: 58 on 2018-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1